# Android Only one item change per fling in gallery

Tags: android, gallery, onfling

I had implemented a custom Gallery with custom Adapter.
My Requirement is that however fast or slow does the user operates fling on the gallery only one item should change in the gallery.
I tried to override the Gallery's `onFling` method

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
    float velocityY) {
//Log.e("VELOCITY ORIGINAL", ""+velocityX);
if (velocityX > 500) {//moving left
    velocityX = 500.0f;
}else if(velocityX < -500){//moving right
    velocityX = -500.0f;
}
//Log.e("VELOCITY MODIFIED", ""+velocityX);
return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
}
```

But this did not produce desired results as sometimes it would flick one item and some times it won't.

Then I tried

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    return false;
}
```

But this completely disabled  fling operation.

What could be the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you have to override the **onFling** method in the **Gallery** class [Try this](http://pastebin.com/TyXTpQ4q) and just Use **ExtendedGallery** instead of **Gallery**

Comment: @hotveryspicy what is OP ??? and what's wrong in suggeting an idea to extend Gallery ?

Comment: OP refer to `original poster`, Here custom Gallery is same what you referring and  OP itself overriding `onFLing()` you can see in question, he mention that "Then I tried..."

Comment: @hotveryspicy I understood that. he is returning **false** ....that's y fling is disabled comlpetely . Instead of that we have to check one condition ... that is what i have posted in the paste bin .. I don't understand what is the mistake in suggesting him that .

Comment: OK, I am rolling back but let OP decide whether your condition will do his job or not, but I think it will not.

Comment: @hotveryspicy i already done this all he want's is to stop the fling i mean to fling one item at a time. Who knows may be you are right in another case if he wants to fling as per user operation, then it will not work. Let's see whether he got what he wanted or not ... :)